# Insert row into database from C# form

Tags: c#, database, insert

```
String ConString =  @"DataSource=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BizContact.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConString);
try
{
   cn.Open();
   MessageBox.Show("connect");
}
catch (Exception)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Did not connect");
}       

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert tableNote values (@UserName,@Note)",cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", textBox2.Text);

try
{
   int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   if (res > 0)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("insert");
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
   cn.Close();
}
```

I am trying to add new row to the database. The above code is correct with no error and it display the try statement but does not insert row into the database. Any idea to solve it.

Comment: try printing value of `res`. It should be 1 because it gives the number of rows inserted.

Comment: Look in your project directory, there may be multiple copies of `BizContact.mdf` Check all of them for your inserted record.

Comment: Try to use SQL Profiler and see the query generated and try to run it in SSMS .

Answer (score 4):

try full T-SQL statement

```
"INSERT INTO table_name (userColumn, noteColumn) VALUES (@UserName, @Note)"
```

also dispose SqlConnection via using state

```
using(SqlConnection  cn = new SqlConnection(ConString))
{
  //....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your insert statement is wrong (missing `into`). Do either:

```
insert into tableNote select @UserName,@Note
```

or

```
insert into tableNote (column_name1, column_name2) values (@UserName,@Note)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up Sql Profiler and watch it execute the command, then try replaying that command into Sql Management Studio.  More than likely, it'll show you that the query is ever so slightly malformed such that it happily does nothing successfully.